# Remove duplicates from xml (two conditions)

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

im searching for a xslt solution for eliminating duplicates in a xml file.
The File is created with a software called epgrab. It grabs epg data from dvb-s transponders and saves it to a *.xml file.
The problem here is that we are reading the epg multiple times a day because some data is changed within a hour or so and we need to have the actual epg data in time. Sometimes it happens that entries have duplicates.
These need to be eliminated because the webserver should not read a 10 megabyte file everytime someone opens our iptv-frontend.

The xml file looks like:

```
    <programme channel="28007.dvb.guide" start="20150811143300 +0200" stop="20150811151800 +0200">
    <title lang="de">Traumstädte: Stockholm - Die Entspannte</title>
    <sub-title lang="de">Film von Ines Trams</sub-title>
    <desc lang="de">Stockholm ist eine schwimmende Metropole mit einzigartiger Stadtgeografie: Jeweils ein Drittel der Stadtfläche b$
    <language>de</language>
    <!--language>mul</language-->
        <!--language>mis</language-->
        <!--language>de</language-->
    <video>
      <aspect>16:9</aspect>
    </video>
    <audio>
      <stereo>stereo</stereo>
    </audio>
    <subtitles type="teletext">
      <language>de</language>
    </subtitles>
  </programme>
```

The problem here is we need to check for channel PID AND start/stop time - not only one condition.
Is that possible in any way with xslt-1.0 ?

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Thanks to Martin Honnen for formatting my code :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 to group items the approach called Muenchian grouping is based on a key so you can define a key `<xsl:key name="group" match="programme" use="concat(@channel, '|', @start, '|', @stop)"/>`, see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml for details.

Comment: Thank you Martin. I tried it with your key provided, but i do not getting it to work properly..

Comment: Consider to edit your question with some sample data you want to order, showing us the result you want for that sample. Your current attempt does not make much sense, given that you have `key('group', @fieldName)` while your elements don't have an attribute named `fieldName`. So you would need to make sure you use the expression that computes the key value e.g. `match="programme[generate-id() = 
                               generate-id(key('group', concat(@channel, '|', @start, '|', @stop))[1])]"`

Comment: Hey Martin, thank you for your answer. Everything works fine now - i changed the "fieldName" to the xsl:key you provided two days ago and now its working. I tried to eliminate entries which look exactly like the code i provided. The file contains the same entries (<programme>) multiple times. Now i was able to eliminate all the duplicates. You saved my day!